# d3 basic animations

Tags: svg, d3.js

Trying to follow along the tutorial [here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html), but there isn't enough code presented to me to bridge the gaps.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/RXpas/) I am working on to accomplish the same thing, with d3 loaded, however, the animation transitions are not concurrently happening, let alone at all, it is just changing the attributes, something I am already familiar with in SVG hard coding with JQuery selectors.  So where am I going wrong, or missing the boat?

```
// example code doesn't work
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle");
circle.style("fill", "steelblue");
circle.attr("cy", 90);
circle.attr("r", 30);

// this does, but animations don't work
d3.selectAll('circle').style("fill", "steelblue");
d3.selectAll('circle').attr("cy", 90);
d3.selectAll('circle').attr("r", 30);
```

I am eventually trying to leverage the tweening of d3, but I cant get the basics off the ground.  Thanks for you help in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example code, svg is previously assigned to a d3 selection object:

```
 var svg = d3.select("#chart-2").append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);
```

Therefore, you can use it to select the child elements, as in the original example.

Eg. your fiddle could be [rewritten like so](http://jsfiddle.net/RXpas/3/):

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg");

//svg is now a d3.selection object.
svg.on("click", function() {
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle");
    circle.style("fill", "steelblue");
    circle.attr("cy", 90);
    circle.attr("r", 30);
});
```

Something to note about binding events using d3:

Within the anonymous function:

- The event is bound to `d3.event`
- The dom element - not the d3.selection object - is bound to `this`
- If you pass an argument to the function, it will be bound to the data which is joined to the element.

Not really code, but should show what I mean:

```
var someD3Selection = d3.select("#someElement");

someD3Selection.on("click", function(boundData) {
    d3.event.preventDefault(); // <-- here's the event
    this; // <-- the actual dom element which is selected in someD3Selection
    d3.select(this); // <-- same as someD3Selection.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? The duration is optional but it's easier to see what's happening when it's a bit slower.

```
$('#svg').on('click', function() {
    d3.selectAll('circle').style("fill", "grey").transition().duration(5000).style("fill", "steelblue").attr("cy", 90).attr("r", 30);
});
```

Comment: I think this is what I want, but is there more code to the examples, but they are just not showing it?

Comment: Yes, use view source to see it. I don't think the examples do it how I did as they use explicit functions for the transitions as far as I can see.